# Export SQL Server table data to excel, text file etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

I want to export the table from the database, When we click on the button that should popup with a window containing different options like excel,text file etc okay and cancel button where the user can select their required option using radio button and as soon as they make a click on the okay button the table should get exported based on their requirement.

```
Public Function GetExport()
Dim cmd2 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
Dim con = New SqlConnection
  ("server = PROG19-PC;database = paginate;Trusted_Connection = yes")
cmd2.Connection = con
con.Open()

Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblMemberDetails", con)
Dim dtMainSQLData As New System.Data.DataTable()
da.Fill(dtMainSQLData)
Dim dcCollection As DataColumnCollection = dtMainSQLData.Columns

' Export Data into EXCEL Sheet
Dim ExcelApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass()
ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing)

' ExcelApp.Cells.CopyFromRecordset(objRS);
For i As Integer = 1 To dtMainSQLData.Rows.Count
    For j As Integer = 1 To dtMainSQLData.Columns.Count
        If i = 1 Then
            ExcelApp.Cells(i, j) = dcCollection(j - 1).ToString()
        Else
            ExcelApp.Cells(i, j) = dtMainSQLData.Rows(i - 1)(j - 1).ToString()
        End If
    Next
Next

ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs("C:\test.xls")
ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
ExcelApp.Quit()
MsgBox("Data Exported Successfully into Excel File")
```

Comment: What is your question? Does this code work? If not what is the problem?

Comment: I want to create a button which shows a popup window(on click) with different export options,which exports the table from database(sql server)  based on type of export format selected from the window, This is the sample code which i have tried, aint working.